# Antiproton proton reaction

Tags: particle-physics, feynman-diagrams

So, I am doing some exercises in Feynman diagrams, and when I have proton and anti-proton reacting to produce only one photon

$$ p + \overline{p} \longrightarrow \gamma $$

Spin, baryon number, charge it is all conserved, what makes it not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To answer this question, compute the total energy $E^2=(pc)^2+(mc^2)^2$ for the massless photon in the reference frame where the proton-antiproton system has zero momentum.

As a commenter points out, the availability of the strong interaction means that the purely electromagnetic channel $p\bar p\to\gamma\gamma$ is also suppressed.  I recall that the dominant decay mode is to an odd number of pions (to conserve the total spatial parity), but I forget whether it's three or five.